# Ktor with Koin DI can't inject, missing clazz

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I am setting up Koin DI on Ktor in this way:

- https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-ktor/ktor/

But I am getting an error: **No value passed for parameter 'clazz'**

My implementation looks like this:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.inject
import services.SomeService

fun Application.registerPropertyRoutes() {
    routing {
        bodySectionRoute() // add more routes for Property page here
    }
}

fun Route.bodySectionRoute() {
    val someService by inject<SomeService>()

    get("/bodySection") {
        // business logic can be connected here
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

**Update**:

[image]

Comment: Compilation or runtime error? If compilation error, please specify which line is throwing the error. If runtime, provide stacktrace.

Comment: Could you please share a complete code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Added actual line of error @m0skit0

Comment: What happens if you pass SomeService::class.java as parameter?

Comment: @m0skit0 BUILD SUCCESSFUL :)
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to `import org.koin.ktor.ext.inject`